# Compiler chooses erroneous overload instead of valid overload

Tags: c++, c++14, overload-resolution

Take a look at this code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

template<typename RandIt, typename T, typename Pred>
auto search_with(RandIt begin, RandIt end, const T& value, Pred&& pred) noexcept {
    //...
    return begin;
}

template<typename RandIt, typename T>
auto search_with(RandIt begin, RandIt end, const T& value) noexcept {
    return search_with(begin, end, value, std::less<T>{});
}

template<typename Array, typename T, typename Pred>
auto search_with(const Array& array, const T& value, Pred&& pred) noexcept {
    return search_with(std::begin(array), std::end(array), value, std::forward<Pred>(pred));
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3 };
    search_with(v, 10, std::less<int>{}); // ok
    search_with(v.begin(), v.end(), 10);  // fail!
}
```

I do not understand why in the second `search_with` call, the compiler selects the third overload. If I comment out the third overload, then the code compiles fine. This indicates that the second overload is not discarded as it does compile, and it should be a valid overload.

However, the third overload is chosen, which fails, as there is no specialization of `std::begin` (and `std::end`) for iterators:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'auto search_with(const Array&, const T&, Pred&&) [with Array = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; T = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; Pred = int]':
main.cpp:23:39:   required from here
main.cpp:17:34: error: no matching function for call to 'begin(const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >&)'
     return search_with(std::begin(array), std::end(array), value, std::forward<Pred>(pred));
                        ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
```

I would have thought that the opposite happens: the third overload is discarded because it fails to compile, and the second one is chosen.

But that is obviously not the case, so what is happening here? Why is the wrong overload being chosen? Why is the third overload a better match then the second one?

Comment: SFINAE applies to the function declaration, not the defintion, which is why enable_if is applied to template arguments or return values, rather than the prettier option of sticking such code in the body. The function's discarded only if the declaration bit fails to compile. The supplied arguments work just fine in the third function's declaration, so it won't be discarded.

Comment: However if you use a trailing return type, it appears to work: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d3d34290d7beb1a

Comment: @AndyG Ah, that's SFINAE. :) Thanks

Comment: @jaggedSpire I would have thought that it also applied to the body, when a "soft" error occurs. Maybe I'm confusing something...

Comment: @Rakete1111 probably they decided against that because then overload resolution would depend on the *contents* of the functions in questions, and there was sufficient chaos already :P

Comment: Function overloading cannot depend on the function body. Consider the situation of *non-template* function overloading. The function body may not be in the header file and are not visible at all at the time when overloading is to be resolved.

Comment: Even if you made it work, relying on template type deduction like this is just a ticking time bomb.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It mostly has to do the third argument, which is an rvalue. Try the following to see why it matches the universal reference better.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
inline void f(T &)
{
    std::cout << "f2" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
inline void f(const T &)
{
    std::cout << "f3" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
inline void f(T &&)
{
    std::cout << "f4" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    const int b = 0;
    int &c = a;
    const int &d = b;
    f(1); // f4 : rvalue matched by universal reference
    f(a); // f2 : lvalue matched by reference, T& preferred to const T&
    f(b); // f3 : lvalue matched by reference, can only do const T&
    f(c); // f2 : lvalue reference matched by reference, T& preferred to const T&
    f(d); // f3 : lvalue const reference matched by reference, can only do const T&
    f(std::move(a)); // f4 : rvalue reference, matched by universal reference

}
```

If you throw one more overload,

```
 template <typename T>
 inline void f(T);
```

into the mix, you will get ambiguous errors, because it will also give you perfect match.

As to the first two rvalue arguments, consider the following example,

```
template <typename T>
inline void f(T)
{
}

template <typename T>
inline void f(const T &)
{
}

int main() { f(1); }
```

You will get an ambiguous error. That is, the two overloads match an rvalue equally well. So they do not determine which overload is selected in your example

Comment: Even more fun, had OP's code taken `pred` by value, partial ordering would have kicked in and chosen the correct overload.

Comment: @T.C. Exactly. Function overloading was fun to play with at first. But these day if possible I just use a tag overloading to save a lot headache. The problem with C++'s overloading is that, even after years struggling, when you have known it in and out, you can still from time to time forget something and get it wrong. The introducing of universal reference into the mix is only making it worse. We are humans , not compilers.

Answer (score 2):

The third overload is always better, except if you pass a const lvalue as third parameter to your function template. You pass a prvalue. The forwarding reference `Pred&&` can match this case better and therefore gets chosen.

You can achieve your desired behavior by using the [SFINAE (Substitution Failure Is Not An Error)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) technique.

```
template<typename Array, typename T, typename Pred>
auto search_with(const Array& array, const T& value, Pred&& pred) noexcept
    -> decltype(search_with(
           std::begin(array), std::end(array), value, std::forward<Pred>(pred)))
{
    return search_with(std::begin(array), std::end(array), value, std::forward<Pred>(pred));
}
```

This will exclude the overload, if the expression in the `decltype(...)` is not valid.

Comment: I figure there is no other way than to remove the duplication, right?

Comment: @Rakete1111 Unfortunately. Maybe in some future C++ standard, but for the moment, you will have to live with the ugliness, if you want proper SFINAE-friendly functions.

Answer (score 0):

The first call is passing parameter values that satisfy the template arguments of *only one* overload:

```
template<typename Array, typename T, typename Pred>
auto search_with(const Array& array, const T& value, Pred&& pred) noexcept
```

The second call is passing parameter values that satisfy the template arguments of *two* overloads:

```
template<typename RandIt, typename T>
auto search_with(RandIt begin, RandIt end, const T& value) noexcept

// where RandIt is std::vector<int>::iterator, and T is int...
```

```
template<typename Array, typename T, typename Pred>
auto search_with(const Array& array, const T& value, Pred&& pred) noexcept

// where Array and T are both std::vector<int>::iterator, and Pred is int...
```

However, the third overload is a better match, because its parameters are all being passed by reference, so no unnecessary copies have to be created by the compiler.

With the second overload, the first two parameters are being passed by value, so extra copies have to be made.  When dealing with class objects (which an STL container's `iterator` type may be), that can affect overload resolution.

The compiler tries to avoid making unnecessary copies when possible.

Comment: Why doesn't the compiler move the iterators instead of copying them?

Comment: I am just thinking that this is the third parameter which makes a difference... 10 is a rvalue and Pred && in the third overload may be a better match then const T & in the second...

Comment: Pass-by-reference is still preferable to moving (less code involved).  And an rvalue can be assigned to a const-reference parameter.  So I think this is still an issue of the compiler preferring to pass the iterators by const-reference instead of invoking extra logic to pass them by value.

Comment: I don' t think it is because that the compiler tries to avoid making copies. When compiler resolve template overloads, whether or not copies are made does not come into play. The three arguments are all rvalues. The second overloads will need to match each of them to an lvalue while the third overload match the first two to lvalue, while the third is matched by a universal reference. Third overload match the third parameter better. It has nothing to do with what compiler "prefers" for any optimization reason. it has to do what is "correct"

Comment: Pass by reference or by value makes no difference to overload resolution. It's got absolutely nothing to do with making copies.